# How to turn integer to string?

Tags: javascript

I can't solve this problem. I want to put backspace between number which will be seem after alert.

For example when I write `23` it must be seems like `2  3` not like `23`.

```
 var xy = prompt("enter a number", " ")
 var count = (xy > 10 && xy < 100) ? alert(xy) : alert("try again");
```

thanks in advence and have a nice day:)

Comment: `xy.replace(/(\d)/, '$1 ')`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var xy = prompt("enter a number", " ")
var count = (xy > 10 && xy < 100) ? alert(nums(xy)) : alert("try again");

function nums(string) {
    var res;
    res = string.split('').join(' ');
    return res;
}
```

and jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/4qbftsy3/

Answer (score 0):

As @dfsq comment

```
var xy = prompt("enter a number", " ")
var count = (xy > 10 && xy < 100) ? alert(xy.replace(/(\d)/, '$1 ')) : alert("try again");
```